# Does Flash Render items that are out of the stage bounds?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is flash smart enough to "hide" PIXELS that aren't on the stage, in order to decrease memory usage? Or I must do it manually, if it decreases the memory usage at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash does not render objects that aren't on the stage (as per http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3e.html).

However I think you may be mixing up two different issues.

One issue is CPU/GPU performance - for this there is no need to worry about off-stage objects as Flash does not waste time rendering display objects that are outside the stage bounds.

The other issue is memory usage. Every object that you create takes up some memory whether or not it is visible on the screen. Flash has a garbage collector that will periodically dispose of unused objects, however "unused objects" means an object that isn't referenced by any other object so if you are having memory issues you will have to manually clean up objects by removing event listeners, nulling references etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like that available to decrease memory usage. If it's visible on your monitor, it needs to be rendered by Flash and have a place in memory storing the pixel colour.

Although Flash is very fast these days, especially with hardware acceleration. So you shouldn't worry too much about performance, there's a lot of bang for your virtual buck with AS3. I'd bet all of my virtual dollars on it.

Answer (score 1):

Flash will store all bitmaps, movieclips in fact all objects in memory as expected. If you have a large bitmap which is larger than the stage, it still occupies memory regardless of you only showing a portion of it.

If you have multiple bitmaps or movieclips that may move off the stage and no part of them are visible, then the only way to recover memory is to make sure the object is dereferenced and set to null.

```
myMovieClip = null;
```

Prior to setting to null you would also have to make sure that nothing else is referencing the object, for example it can't be stored in an array or have any event listeners attached to it so therefore:

```
myMovieClip.removeEventListener(Event.WHATEVER, eventHandler);
```

For bitmapdata objects you would need to call dispose first before setting to null:

```
myBitmapdata.dispose();
myBitmapdata = null;
```

This then allows the GC to recover memory when it chooses, unless you are using AIR which means you may request a gc call yourself:

```
System.gc();
```

If you are developing in Flash Builder, the best practice is to regularly profile your application and hit the button to force a gc call. You can then see which objects are persisting in memory and locate the references which are causing the memory leaks.

Comment: Didn't ask about garbage collecting. Know how to build up an application in an efficient way.
Just asked if there's a way to disallow flash to render pixels that aren't on stage, but it seems, flash does it automatically.

Comment: No worries, I just took the angle I thought most appropriate.